# Manually Use LEDs on RJ45 Connector

Tags: rj45

I am using RJ45 connectors(2-406549-1) with built in LEDs, to transmit SPI lines for a microcontroller project(I needed CAT 6 cables for twisted data/ground pairs).
I'd like to use those built in LEDs to notify when the PCB has power, but I can't find any information on what those LEDs are to determine how I can power them.

Any ideas where to find that? I'm guessing RJ45 connectors with LEDs must have a standard LED type but I can't find what that is.

Comment: I would not assume that there is some "standard" and that all such LEDs are the same. Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the connectors you want to use.

Comment: If you are talking about the activity LEDs on many network adapters?  They are not standard (or even present on) to all connectors.

Comment: Link to part: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/2-406549-1/1122133?s=N4IgTCBcDa4LQBYAMA2ArAgnHAjCAugL5A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [datasheet](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=406549&DocType=Customer%20Drawing&DocLang=English):

[image]

you can see the LED pinout. For your module, `406549-1` the table to the right on the datasheet says these are yellow and green. Yellow LEDs typically have a \$V_f\$ of around 2.1 V; green LEDs typically around 2 V. The datasheet doesn't give any other information, but you could almost certainly drive 5 mA through them to get decent brightness. If you're running a 3V3 supply, a 220 \$\Omega\$ resistor in series would be fine.